# To detect the screenlock even when the app is sleeping

Tags: android, wakelock

I have an android application that needs to be locked (redirect to the login page) whenever the user presses the lock button. The user can lock the phone while on my application or while on other applications/home screen. In both of these scenarios, I need my application to be locked.

This is working fine in case the phone is locked from an application :

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    boolean isScreenOn = pm.isInteractive();
    if (!isScreenOn) {
        LogUtils.logD(TAG, "Screen is off, Locking the application");
        // Lock the application code
    }
}
```

But I am not able to figure out the second scenario when the user has moved away from the application and then locks it. I do not want to start a service or any background thread for this purpose.

Comment: use a broadcast receiver that fires on screen lock.
Have a look
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34564744/8528047

Answer (score 0):

Try to add else and return at the end of the code so the activity will still awake in background process

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
super.onStop();
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
boolean isScreenOn = pm.isInteractive();
if (!isScreenOn) {
    LogUtils.logD(TAG, "Screen is off, Locking the application");
    // Lock the application code
} else{
  return true;
}
```